# Oracle PL/SQL - How to delete multiple duplicate records in the SQL table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table name TABLE1 that contains duplicate records as shown below:

```
ID  TYPE  AMOUNT NUMBER      DATE
--- ----  ------ ------ ---------
1    AAA   10.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
2    AAA    2.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
3    AAA   10.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
4    AAA    2.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
5    AAA   10.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
6    AAA    2.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
7    AAA   10.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
8    AAA    2.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
...  ...     ...    ...       ...
100  AAA   10.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11
101  AAA    2.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11
```

In this case, I would like to remove ALL duplicate combination rows, except two using SQL or/via PL/SQL where AMOUNT (10.00 and 2.00). In addition, the duplicate recordes containing different amounts could be more than two such as shown below:

```
ID  TYPE  AMOUNT NUMBER      DATE
--- ----  ------ ------ ---------
1    AAA   10.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
2    AAA    2.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
3    AAA   15.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
4    AAA   25.50 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
5    AAA   10.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
6    AAA    2.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
7    AAA   15.00 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
8    AAA   25.50 AAA123 22-JUN-11 
...
```

In the above example, I need to delete only 4 out of 8 records, where AMOUNT should remain 4 records (10.00, 2.00, 15.00 and 25.50). In other words, I have multiple groups of duplicates in one table (2 records for one, 4 for another, etc) - multiple rows where more than one exists.

Comment: So what columns contribute to DUPLICATES? Only amount?

Comment: The community frowns on tagging PLSQL when the answer really only uses SQL.  For what version of Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DELETE 
    FROM  TABLE1
    WHERE ROWID IN 
    (
        SELECT ROW_ID_VAL
          FROM 
            (
                SELECT a.*, 
                       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY AMOUNT ORDER BY ID DESC) RN, ROWID row_id_val
                  FROM TABLE1 a
            )
            WHERE rn <> 1
    )
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` might be a better choice in this situation?

Comment: @OMG Pointes: I presume Id field is unique and RANK shuold still be fine as I am ordering the data in a window using ID.

Answer (score 2):

The DATE column is the only one that needs more info; otherwise use:

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM YOUR_TABLE t
                WHERE t.type = YOUR_TABLE.type
                  AND t.amount = YOUR_TABLE.amount
                  AND t.number = YOUR_TABLE.number
                  AND t.date = YOUR_TABLE.date
             GROUP BY t.type, t.amount, t.number, t.date
               HAVING MIN(t.id) != YOUR_TABLE.id)
```

The `YOUR_TABLE.`column references refer to the outer YOUR_TABLE, the table the deletion is to be performed on.  This gives it a correlated subquery effect, but `EXISTS` doesn't quite function that way.

Answer (score 1):

One method you may follow is as the following:

Each row has a unique `(row id)`.  You can identify the duplicated rows of course and then delete the duplicated rows based on `(row id)`. Just type the following `SELECT` statement to reveal the duplicated rows id:

`SELECT rowid  from table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE

BEGIN

  for rec_ in (
                 SELECT type, amount, number, date , count(1) record_count
                    FROM table 1
                  GROUP BY type, amount, number, date
                 HAVING count(1) > 1) loop

      counter_ := 0;

      for rec2_ in ( select * from table1 where rec_.type = type
                                            and rec_.amount = amount
                                            and rec_.number = number
                                            and rec_.date = date) loop

            counter_ := counter_ + 1;            
            exit when counter_ = rec_.record_count;
            delete from table1 where id = rec2_.id;
       End loop;

  end loop;
END;
```