# How to remove duplicate rows keeping other unique rows alive?

Tags: database, oracle

Below is the records which my table contains. I want to remove all duplicate rows and the result must contain rows having IDs 50, 10, 20, 30, 40.

Thanks

```
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
50 Engineering    Pune
10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
30 SALES          CHICAGO
40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to delete the duplicates in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017027/sql-to-delete-the-duplicates-in-a-table) or [Oracle PL/SQL - How to delete multiple duplicate records in the SQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455941/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-delete-multiple-duplicate-records-in-the-sql-table?rq=1)

Comment: U want to delete duplicates form database table..or u want to query it without duplicates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different thing between same rows in oracle is that all the rows got unique rowid
there for you can just use min or max of rowid with group by all your columns
the query is this:

```
DELETE FROM tableName
WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MAX (ROWID)
                 FROM   tableName
                 GROUP BY ID, NAME, place
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'd do this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0ea9/7

```
delete example
where rowid in (
    select r_id
    from (
        select 
            rowid r_id, 
            row_number() over(partition by e.dep_id, e.dep_name, e.place order by e.dep_id) rnum
        from example e
    )
    where rnum > 1
);
```

the analytic function `row_number() over()` determines which rows to be deleted; you want to delete the 2nd, 3rd and so on i.e. `rnum > 1`. I use rowid because you don't seem to have a primary key on your table (is that a good idea?).

Answer (score 0):

Using `MIN(rowid)`:

```
DELETE FROM table
 WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MIN (ROWID)
                     FROM   table
                     GROUP BY ID, NAME, place
                     );
```

Refer this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/deleting-duplicate-rows-in-oracle/), this will show you the different ways of deleting duplicated data from a table.